# Is it possible to divide up boundingBox?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, intersect

In cocos2d, i've got two objects that I want to detect collision with.
Im using CGrectintersectsrect, which has been working fine thus far.
But I want to divide up the bounding box of one of my objects into 4 quarters, so that if my object collides in any one of these quarters, appropriate physics can then be applied.

At the moment, there is only 1 large boundingBox which is insufficient. Ideally I would want 4+...

Is this possible, and if so how could i achieve this?
If not, is there any other avenue that could work?
Thanks everyone, once again :)

Comment: Bump? Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundingbox method returns a CGRect. You have to divide your rect manualy, there is no pre-made method for that.
Otherwise if there is a lot of objects, the best way to detect the collisions is to use Box2d. You can follow this tuto to see
[How To Use Box2D For Just Collision Detection with Cocos2D iPhone](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone) tutorial.